# Kernel Page allocation failure while using the network subsytem

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, device-driver, network-driver

I am developing a driver for exchanging data by using psnap modules. But I am getting the following crash. How do I solve this crash? How do I work out what's causing the problem? My kernel version is 4.9.41.

```
 125.911986] , *pmd=00000000[  125.914637] Internal error: Oops: 206 [#4] PREEMPT SMP ARM
[  125.920145] Modules linked in: sample_gadget(O) libcomposite(O) psnap(O) 
llc(O) bc_example(O) sha512_generic sha512_arm sha256_generic sha1_generic sha1)
[  126.000132] CPU: 1 PID: 500 Comm: systemd-logind Tainted: G      D    O    4.9.41-ge3a80a1c5c #1
[  126.008949] Hardware name: Generic DRA74X (Flattened Device Tree)
[  126.015064] task: ed210000 task.stack: ed31c000
[  126.019621] PC is at __kmalloc_track_caller+0xa8/0x1d8
[  126.019671] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 01092a85
[  126.019675] pgd = d57867c0
[  126.019681] [01092a85] *pgd=95795003, *pmd=00000000
[  126.039624] LR is at get_mem_cgroup_from_mm+0xd4/0x12c
[  126.044781] pc : [<c03209fc>]    lr : [<c0323414>]    psr: 200f0013
[  126.044781] sp : ed31dc78  ip : ed31dc30  fp : ed31dc9c
[  126.056303] r10: 00000000  r9 : 00001d1e  r8 : ed31dc78
[  126.061547] r7 : ed31c000  r6 : 01092a85  r5 : 025106c0  r4 : ee801c00
[  126.068098] r3 : 00000000  r2 : 2deda000  r1 : 00001d1e  r0 : ee801c00
[  126.074650] Flags: nzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
[  126.081812] Control: 30c5387d  Table: ad24bd80  DAC: 55555555
[  126.087578] Process systemd-logind (pid: 500, stack limit = 0xed31c210)

[  126.336637] Backtrace: 
[  126.339103] [<c0320954>] (__kmalloc_track_caller) from [<c079e308>] (__kmalloc_reserve.constprop.15+0x2c/0x78)
[  126.349144]  r9:0000000a r8:00000100 r7:c079fd74 r6:025004c0 r5:025004c0 r4:ed31dccf
[  126.356920] [<c079e2dc>] (__kmalloc_reserve.constprop.15) from [<c079fd74>] (__alloc_skb+0x60/0x144)
[  126.366088]  r9:0000000a r8:00000000 r7:ee801cc0 r6:025004c0 r5:0000000a r4:ca4da240
[  126.373864] [<c079fd14>] (__alloc_skb) from [<c079fea8>] (alloc_skb_with_frags+0x50/0x1d4)
[  126.382160]  r9:0000000a r8:00000003 r7:c026e1f8 r6:00000000 r5:7fffffff r4:ee01de40
[  126.389935] [<c079fe58>] (alloc_skb_with_frags) from [<c07968b8>] (sock_alloc_send_pskb+0x1f0/0x20c)
[  126.399104]  r10:00000000 r9:0000000a r8:ee01df84 r7:c026e1f8 r6:ed31c000 r5:7fffffff
[  126.406960]  r4:ee01de40
[  126.409505] [<c07966c8>] (sock_alloc_send_pskb) from [<c084d8b8>] (unix_dgram_sendmsg+0x138/0x648)
[  126.418500]  r10:00000016 r9:00000000 r8:0000000a r7:dff2b500 r6:ee01de40 r5:ed31df48
[  126.426356]  r4:00000000
[  126.428901] [<c084d780>] (unix_dgram_sendmsg) from [<c07942ac>] (sock_sendmsg+0x1c/0x2c)
[  126.437023]  r10:00004000 r9:00000000 r8:ed31de28 r7:dff2b500 r6:00000000 r5:00000000
[  126.444880]  r4:ed31df48
[  126.447423] [<c0794290>] (sock_sendmsg) from [<c0794808>] (___sys_sendmsg+0x1d8/0x1e8)
[  126.455371] [<c0794630>] (___sys_sendmsg) from [<c079553c>] (__sys_sendmsg+0x48/0x74)
[  126.463231]  r10:00000000 r9:ed31c000 r8:c0207d84 r7:00000128 r6:dff2b500 r5:00004000
[  126.471089]  r4:be80da10
[  126.473630] [<c07954f4>] (__sys_sendmsg) from [<c0795578>] (SyS_sendmsg+0x10/0x14)
[  126.481227]  r6:00000010 r5:be80dfa3 r4:be80da10
[  126.485864] [<c0795568>] (SyS_sendmsg) from [<c0207be0>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x34)
```

Comment: Hard to say without looking at code. Does it always happen? How long after loading the module?

Comment: It will happens after some time of loading the modules loading. Can't able to figure out why and where it is happening.

Comment: What is a PSNAP Module? Are you trying to create a netdevice device driver for it?

Comment: i am not creating net_device object but using the psnap modules whose path is in net/802/ in linux source code. I am using proto->request function pointer to send the data to the net subsystem.